# Simple-xml: how to annotate my "point" class

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I have to represent in an Android program a data structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<points>
    <point id="La Gioconda">
       <rssi id="north">-55</rssi>
       <rssi id="east" >-76</rssi>
       <rssi id="south">-64</rssi>
       <rssi id="east" >-92</rssi>
    </point>
    <point id="La Pietà">
       <rssi id="north">-51</rssi>
       <rssi id="east" >-60</rssi>
       <rssi id="south">-88</rssi>
       <rssi id="east" >-59</rssi>
    </point>
</points>
```

Below I report the classes Points, Point and Rssi I used, getting this error:

```
05-03 07:49:19.884: DEBUG/com.marcos.training.TrainingActivity(354): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'dbm' protected java.lang.Integer com.marcos.training.Rssi.dbm for class com.marcos.training.Rssi at line 4
```

For sure I miss something obvious... :-(

File Points.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

@Element
public class Points {
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private List<Point> list;

    public Integer getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public List<Point> getList() {
       return list;
    }
}
```

File Point.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

import android.util.Log;

@Root
public class Point {
    private final static String TAG = TrainingActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private List<Rssi> list;

    @Attribute
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getRssi(String id) {
        int len = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                return list.get(i).getDbm();
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getRssi(): unforeseen id \"" + id + "\"");
        return 999;
    }
}
```

File Rssi.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Rssi {

    @Attribute
    protected String id;

    @Element
    protected Integer rssi;

    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public Integer getRssi() {
      return rssi;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your `Rssi` class. The `rssi` element does not have a child element so the following annotation is **incorrect**:

```
@Element
protected Integer rssi;
```

You need to use the `@Text` annotation instead:

```
@Text
protected Integer rssi;
```

**Alternatively**, it would be better to use an `ElementMap` to hold the rssi mappings, instead of a list. For example, you could change your `Point` class to:

```
@Root
public class Point {

    @ElementMap(entry="rssi", key="id", attribute=true, inline=true)
    private Map<String,Integer> rssiMap;

    @Attribute
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getRssi(String id) {
        Integer val = rssiMap.get(id);
        if(val == null){
            return 999;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did follow your second suggestion  to use an ElementMap, but, when serializing my new points class, I get this exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '          ' as integer: should I change somehow my poinys.xml structure, or do I miss something else?

Comment: Post scriptum: in the simple quotes I have some spaces, a new-line, and more spaces...

Comment: @Marcos a space is not is not a valid integer, hence the NumberFormatException. You might want to use a String instead of an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should remove `@Root` from Rssi and Point classes, as they are not the roots of the xml.

Second, you apparently have you classes or xml old here, as the error is related to some "dbm" field, which is missed in xml and java code. I assume, that in the newer version you have something like:

```
 <rssi id="north" dbm="55"/>
```

Then all you need is in the Rssi class:

```
  @Attribute
  private Integer dbm;
```